# Rails: OAuth gem dependency error w/ bundler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, omniauth, faraday-oauth

Trying to start the server and I'm getting this:

```
/Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@webapp/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require': no such file to load -- addressable/uri (LoadError)
from /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@webapp/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
from /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@webapp/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
from /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@webapp/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
from /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@webapp/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@webapp/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
from /Users/Ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@webapp/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/faraday-0.7.5/lib/faraday/connection.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I've tried a number of versions, deleting the Gemfile.lock, updating the bundler, etc.  I've searched a lot of the threads around and it there looks to be a conflict between OmniAuth and devise but not with my error.  Version conflict?  How do you diagnose?

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
require 'rubygems'

gem 'rails'
gem 'actionpack'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'haml'
gem "devise", :git => "https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git"
# gem 'oa-core'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-openid'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-github'
gem "settingslogic"
gem 'composite_primary_keys'
gem 'addressable'
# gem 'faraday'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'pg'
gem 'squeel'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.6'
gem "bcrypt-ruby", :require => "bcrypt"

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
  gem 'hpricot', :require => false #html2haml
  gem 'ruby_parser', :require => false # html2haml
  gem 'pickle'
  gem 'awesome_print', :require => 'ap'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :development do
  gem 'heroku', :require => false
  gem 'sass'
end

group :test do
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'spork', '~> 0.9.0.rc3'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It actually was a ownership issue the dependent gem was installed as root. I updated the ownership all the directories and files in the gems directory and it worked.  If you have a problem installing (i.e. generate native code) a gem where you sudo it, remember to go back and change the ownership of files back in the gems directory back to your user account